# Set ID for input elements when creating them dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, input, textbox, uniqueidentifier

How can I set an input field ID when creating them dynamically when the user clicks a button. 
I have a text field and a combo box pair which will be created on click. So every time the user clicks and creates one pair, I need to assign them unique IDs so that these value pairs can be saved to an array for later retrieval.

```
function createattr() {
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    input.placeholder="Attribute name";
    input.className = "attr-textfield-style";
    inputval.appendChild(input);

    //Display the drop down menu

    var newDiv=document.createElement('div');
    var html = '<select>', attrtypes = typeGenerate(), i;
    for(i = 0; i < attrtypes.length; i++) {
        html += "<option value='"+attrtypes[i]+"'>"+attrtypes[i]+"</option>";
    }
    html += '</select>';
    newDiv.className="attr-combobox-style";
    newDiv.innerHTML= html;
    inputval.appendChild(newDiv);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. It was this one simple line.Just wanted to share this for future references.

```
input.id="attr"+attrID;
```

with attrID being declared as a global variable that is incremented before the function ends so that each input field is assigned a unique ID

I just added the 'attr' string to an ID so that the combobox selected along with this text field will have the same numeral (i.e. One pair-> text field id- attr3, combobox- type3. The next pair will have -> text field id- attr4, combobox- type4)

Answer (score 0):

if the elements never get deleted, you could count existing elements and give ID accordingly, like:

```
var newId = document.getElementsByClassName('attr-combobox-style').length;
input.id = 'attr' + newId;
```

Or you could use timestamp, it will be absolutely unique:

```
input.id = 'attr' + new Date().getTime();
```

Comment: Since in my case, the elements can be deleted upon selection, I can't use this,though the timestamp sounds great. I'll get on with it. Thanks for the suggestion,